# In what tier should my web service references be?

Tags: web-services, architecture, dependency-injection, n-tier-architecture

I have the following structure in my web solution:

- Domain
- DataAccess
- ApplicationServices
- Web
- Tests

I have some application services that I am using to abstract some web services that I am using.  (Specifically, I am bundling some shipping web services together into a single application service.)  Should my Application Services layer reference the web services I am consuming, and the other tiers remain ignorant, or should I reference the web services in the Web and Tests tiers and inject the web services into the application service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [Service Gateway](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998420.aspx) pattern to work with Web Services, so I would have another project called ServiceGateway as an additional tier to my application and this will be referenced by ApplciationServices, as stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998554.aspx)..

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the kind of thing I am looking for.